# strip_tags not working

Tags: php, mysql, html, filter, strip-tags

I am truing to filter html characters out like this

```
$user = $_POST["user"]; //Get username from <form>
mysql_real_escape_string($user); //Against SQL injection
strip_tags($user); //Filter html characters out
```

But for some reason this is not filtering html characters out. I don't know why, could it by `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Comment: Which kind of HTML characters are not filtered out? [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags) will not filter out all HTML, just some tags. Next to that, blindly applying some esacpe or strip functions does not add much security, you need to know what you specifically do. That's the hard point about input validation, sanitization and building database queries.

Comment: It's also in the wrong order (even if strip_tags is unlikely to undo the escaping).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

...But, do you mean:

```
$user = $_POST["user"]; // Get username from <form>
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($user); // Against SQL injection
$user = strip_tags($user); // Filter html characters out
```

?

As said in the other answers (referring to `strip_tags()`, but it's the same for `mysql_real_escape_string()`), these functions do not alter strings directly, but return the modified *copy*. So you have to assign return values to the same (or another) variable!

Comment: Sound good but standard way is strip_tags(html_entity_decode($user))

Answer (score 6):

```
strip_tags($user); //Filter html characters out
```

should be replaced with this:

```
$user = strip_tags($user); //Filter html characters out
```

`strip_tags` returns the stripped value

See doc: http://nl2.php.net/strip_tags

This is the same with `mysql_real_escape_string()`

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($user); //Against SQL injection
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags) improperly:

> string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )

Modifying the code to assign it to a return value should fix it

```
$user = strip_tags($user); //Filter html characters out
```

**EDIT**

Just for completeness sakes, thanks for lorenzo-s for pointing it out, you also need to do the same to the `mysql_real_escape_string`

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($user); // Against SQL injection
```

Comment: If this is the problem, he does the same error on `mysql_real_escape_string()` too.

Answer (score 1):

As already said

```
$user = strip_tags($user);
```

should be used, but I'd also put

```
mysql_real_escape_string($user);
```

AFTER the call to strip_tags();

Comment: Shouldn't matter in the slightest the order of `strip_tags` / `mysql_real_escape_string`. As far as personal preference, I would agree.