# How to show array name after echo?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, magento, datatable

I have an array of options that is used in a form's drop down select input.

DATA.php file that holds the array info...

```
'options' =>  array("Car", "SUV", "Pickup", "Van", "Bus", "Motorcycle");
```

Edit page that displays the form and calls the options for the drop down input..

```
echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$optionValue.'">'.$optionLabel.'</option>';
```

when the form is saved the array option position value is saved to my database. I have a table on another page that echos some of the information the user submitted. But because the information is being pulled from the database as is, the information shows up as either, 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. which is the arrays position value (example: 0=car, 1=Suv, 2=pickup, etc.)

this displays the table...

```
<tr>
<td><span class="nobr"><?php echo $_sublogin->getData('vehicle_type') ?>
</span></td>
</tr>
```

How do i display the information back, so the table knows if the value is 1 echo SUV, etc.

I'm pretty new at php and i feel this is something i should know how to do but i dont. please help!

thank you.

Comment: values of your `$option` array is fixed?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580191/strip-tags-not-working] this might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is probably because $optionValue contains 0,1,2... Page submits value part of the dropdown list (value="'.$optionValue.'"). I think $optionLabel has the values car, SUV... etc. So what you can do is replace $optionValue with $optionLabel.

`echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$optionLabel.'">'.$optionLabel.'</option>';`
That will save the label value to the database.

Answer (score 1):

if i understood your problem then you can use if/else condition for showing name against their value. like this-

```
<?php
if($_sublogin->getData('vehicle_type') == 1):
?>
<tr>
<td><span class="nobr"> SUB </span></td>
</tr>
<?php
elseif($_sublogin->getData('vehicle_type') == 2):
?>
<tr>
<td><span class="nobr"> CAR </span></td>
</tr>
.
.
.
.
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this:

```
$arr['options']=array("Car", "SUV", "Pickup", "Van", "Bus", "Motorcycle");
echo $arr['options'][1];

//output: SUV
```